# How properly use Gstreamer in QtWidget?

Tags: qt, qt5, video-streaming, gstreamer-1.0

I want to play a local file inside the QVideowidget by using the gstreamer. I tested gstreamer in the terminal without any problem with:
`gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! autovideosink`,and it showed this

[image]

But when I came to Qt,

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMediaPlayer>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QVideoWidget>
#include <gst/gst.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);

QVideoWidget *videoWidget = new QVideoWidget;
QMediaPlayer *player  = new QMediaPlayer;
videoWidget->show();

player->setVideoOutput(videoWidget);
player->setMedia(QUrl("gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! autovideosink"));
//    player->setMedia(QUrl("gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! xvimagesink name=\"qtvideosink\""));
//    player->setMedia(QUrl("gst-pipeline udpsrc port=5801 ! application/x-rtp,payload=   (int)96,encoding-name=(string)H264,clock-rate=(int)90000 ! rtpjitterbuffer latency=50 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! omxh264dec ! videoconvert ! ximagesink"));
player->play();

return a.exec();
}
```

and in my .pro file I put these:

```
CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += gstreamer-1.0
PKGCONFIG += gstreamer-video-1.0
```

I faced the following error:

```
DirectShowPlayerService::doSetUrlSource: Unresolved error code 0x80040216 (IDispatch error #22)
```

the output is:

[image]

I searched a lot, but I couldn't solve the issue. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: I don't understand your url `QUrl("gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! autovideosink")`?  I wouldn't expect that to do anything useful.

Comment: @G.M. Thanks for your attention. I guess, too, that the problem is related to this URL, but I don't know how to fix that. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could play a video test inside the Qwidget with the below method. Be aware that picking a compatible sink is essential. for more information about  sink (and other elements), use `gst-inspect-1.0 | findstr sink` in the terminal.

```
#include <gst/gst.h>;
#include <gst/video/videooverlay.h>;
#include <QApplication>;
#include <QTimer>;
#include <QWidget>;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  app.connect(&app, SIGNAL(lastWindowClosed()), &app, SLOT(quit ()));

  if (!g_thread_supported ())
  g_thread_init (NULL);
  gst_init (&argc, &argv);

  // prepare the pipeline
  GstElement *pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("xvoverlay");
  GstElement *src  = gst_element_factory_make ("videotestsrc", NULL);
  GstElement *sink = gst_element_factory_make ("glimagesink", NULL);
  gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), src, sink, NULL);
  gst_element_link (src, sink);
  // getting more information
  gst_debug_set_active(true);
  gst_debug_set_default_threshold(GST_LEVEL_WARNING);

  QWidget window;
  window.resize(320, 240);
  window.show();
  WId xwinid = window.winId();
  gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle (GST_VIDEO_OVERLAY (sink), xwinid);

  // run the pipeline

  GstStateChangeReturn sret = gst_element_set_state (pipeline,
  GST_STATE_PLAYING);
  if (sret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref (pipeline);
  // Exit application
  QTimer::singleShot(0, QApplication::activeWindow(), SLOT(quit()));
  }

  int ret = app.exec();
  window.hide();
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref (pipeline);

  return ret;
}
```

the output inside widget:

[image]